# I can print a state object array, but when I try to access a value from an object in the array, the whole object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to React and trying to add a list of markers to a google map component using the `google-map-react` library.

What I've done so far:

1. Fetched object data from my API
2. Stored each object in the 'markers' array in the component state with the following structure

```
[
  {
   "id":1,
   "lat":123.123,
   "lng":23.13,
   "color":"red"
   },{
   "id":11,
   "lat":53.274,
   "lng":-6.25,
   "color":"red"
  }
]
```

Now I'm trying to access the marker array from the JSX, which I can access fine using `this.state.markers` or `this.state.markers[0]`, but whenever I try to access a value stored in one of the array's objects with `this.state.markers[0].id`, it shows as `undefined`.

Here `this.state.markers[1]` is working fine

[image: this.state.markers[1] working fine]

Uncommenting `this.state.markers[1].id` breaks it

[image: Uncommenting this.state.markers[1].id breaking it]

React dev tools showing state values

[image: React dev tools showing state values]
The full code:

```
class GoogleMap extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 53.35,
      lng: -6.26
    },
    zoom: 13,

  };

  state = {
    markers: [

    ]
  };

  async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "/api/crime/all";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)

    //Create a copy of the current markers array
    var newMarkers = this.state.markers.slice();
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
      console.log(data[i].id)
      var marker = {
        id: data[i].id,
        lat: data[i].latitude,
        lng: data[i].longitude,
        color: "red"
      }
      //Push each object to the array
      newMarkers.push(marker);
    }

    // Update the state with the new array
    this.setState({markers: newMarkers});

  }
  render() {

    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "AIzaSyA7qsNPuWR4K4RncWMv1sFfxUIJG-7zOh0" }}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
          options={createMapOptions}  
        >

          {/* Here Im trying to access the array from the jsx */}
          {console.log("Markers        "+ JSON.stringify(this.state.markers))}
          {console.log("Markers[0]     "+ JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[0]))}
          {console.log("Markers[1]     "+ JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[1]))}

          /*The below line is what causes the error (Cannot access id of undefined)*/
          {/* {console.log("Markers[1].id  "+ JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[1].id))} */}



          {/* Some hardcoded Markers for now */}
          <Marker
          id={1}
          lat={53.352}
          lng={-6.264}
          color="green"
          />
          <Marker
          id={2}
          lat={53.3512}
          lng={-6.26234}
          color="red"
          />
          <Marker
          id={3}
          lat={53.354}
          lng={-6.2632}
          color="orange"
          />

        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleMap;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data hasn't been fetched on the first render, so all you have is your default values.

`markers` is set to an empty array by default, so you can access it fine. Accessing `markers[x]` will return undefined which is acceptable too. Accessing `markers[x].property` is treating undefined as if it were an object, which will break.

Check to see if your data has finished loading before trying to access it.

You can do this by conditionally rendering the whole component:

```js
if (this.state.markers.length > 0) {
  return // your components
} else {
  return null // or whatever else you choose
}
```

Or you can just check to see if it exists before accessing it.